Not able to get data from LSN50v2-D20 Dragino Temperature Sensor
I had got a sensor from this link, which is a Lorawan capable Dragino temperature sensor.
https://www.choovio.com/product/d20s-lb-lorawan-waterproof-outdoor-temperature-sensor/?attribute_solar-powered=No&srsltid=AfmBOoq79x-Blwt63gtjVnq9OB4HuUSJzElX0sLnKzZsk1SYmcES91s4I1g
I am planning to use this to connect to a public lorawan gateway and get data from it. For this I added to device to https://console.meteoscientific.com/ by entering all the details required for OTAA.
The issue is that the device, only one time, sent a Join Request and I can see Join Accept being sent back but that's all. This was just one time and after this I don't see anything more coming in from the sensor, no data packets and no more join request after being rebooted/reset. Any help to debug this issue would be appreciated.
Thanks!

How do you perform the reboot/reset? Can you connect via BLE? Do you have your own gateway you could use for testing? Is the gateway actually online? How far is it? Do you have line of sight to the gateway? What were the RSSI and SNR of the Join Request? Have you tried getting closer to the gateway?

I suggest the following approach/steps for debugging:

Move as close as possible to the gateway and press "Reset". Maybe your node did not received the Join Accept msg.
Measure the battery voltage of your LSN50v2. I own several LSN50v2 and for some reason in two nodes the battery voltage suddenly dropped to an unusable level (Don't know why. I replaced the battery & capacitor with a simple lipo battery called "EEMB LP103454")
If you own a gateway, check its logs for uplink/downlink msgs from/to your node.
Check the serial output of your LSN50v2 (e.g., by connecting TX and ground to a raspberry pi board; pin configuration as indicated in LSN50v2's official manual)

